# How to implement a custom JsonConverter .NET to serialize and deserialize an object for firestore

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, google-cloud-firestore, json-deserialization

I'm trying to create a custom json converter for an object with nested objects to send as a body to the Firestore REST API :

```
public class Channel
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public long OwnerId { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string UserId{ get; private set; }
    public string Pseudonym { get; private set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public long SenderUserId { get; private set; }
    public string text { get; private set; }
    public DateTime SentDate { get; private set; }
}
```

When serialized, the json structure should look like this :

```
{
        "OwnerId": {
            "stringValue": "id-1"
        },
        "Name": {
            "stringValue": "New Channel"
        },
        "Messages": {
            "arrayValue": {
                "values": [
                    {
                        "mapValue": {
                            "fields": {
                                "ConversationMessage": {
                                    "stringValue": "Hello kev"
                                },
                                "SenderUserId": {
                                    "stringValue": "id-1"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Users": {
            "arrayValue": {
                "values": [
                    {
                        "mapValue": {
                            "fields": {
                                "UserId": {
                                    "stringValue": "id-1"
                                },
                                "Pseudonym": {
                                    "stringValue": "raven"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "mapValue": {
                            "fields": {
                                "UserId": {
                                    "stringValue": "id-2"
                                },
                                "Pseudonym": {
                                    "stringValue": "kev"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Firestore imposes this structure, a property becomes an object with the type as a key and the value as a value (string becomes stringValue, IEnumerable becomes arrayValue with values, object becomes mapValue with fields ...  )

Should I create a converter per object or only one converter for the Channel object ? Any answers or help would be very appreciated, thanks !

Comment: I'm afraid this is too broad for Stack Overflow. You're going to have to give it a go and come back here when you're stuck.

Comment: *Should I create a converter per object or only one converter for the Channel object ?* - yes. Either approach could probably work. Personally, I'd probably create a `StringConverter` and `ArrayConverter`, etc.

Comment: In your data model `OwnerId` is a `long` but in the JSON it's clearly a string: `"stringValue": "id-1"`.  Is this a mistake or is there some custom transformation rule for IDs?  Do you have a list of rules necessary for transforming regular JSON to firestore JSON?  For instance the nested `Message` gets a `"mapValue"` property but the root object `Channel` does not.